# Як українською перекласти "пупырышки" на огірках

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Шукав як назвати ... на огірках. На r2u перекладу нема.

[Ось знайшов таке](http://www.kray.ck.ua/kultura/mova/item/17855-yak-vi-tse-nazivaete):

> Огірки бувають гладенькі, а бувають у горбиках, на кінчиках яких у молодих огірків жорсткі ворсинки. Як ви називаєте ці горбики? Часто чуємо запозичене — «пупиришки». А як по-нашому?
>
> В одній із мовознавчих спільнот у соцмережі «Фейсбук» учасники на це відповіли: *горбики, колючки, пухирці, дзьобики, пипки, пуцьвірки, пуп’яшки, шипи, пупирки, пупирці…*

Але більшість цих слів теж не шукається. Тож як перекласти *пупырышки*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [ВИ́ПИН](http://sum.in.ua/s/vypyn), у, *чол*. Місце, що випинається. *Ліве передсердя у людини має невеликий випин — так зване вушко серця* (Наука і життя, 3, 1957, 16).
>
> <sub>*Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 1, 1970. — Стор. 450.*</sub>

Ось ще один з рідкісних прикладів вживання:

> Сформована з каміння, обмазаного глиною та гіпсом, вгорі колона вужчала й мала дивні *випини*, що надавали їй подібности до стилізованого торса людини з плечима.
>
> <sub>Ян Морис. *Чому Захід панує - натепер.* З англ. пер. Ольга Кочерга</sub>

Comment: "Випин" це все ж таки "выступ".

Comment: @OlenaLisovs'ka гадаєте, що це слово не підходить, щоб назвати те, що огірках?

Answer (score 5):

> [ПУХИРЕ́ЦЬ](http://sum.in.ua/s/pukhyrecj), рця, чол. Зменш.-пестл. до пухир. Віспа — тяжка гострозаразна хвороба. У людини, яка захворіла на неї, з'являються характерні ознаки: пухирці на шкірі і слизових оболонках, лихоманка (Вечірній Київ, 29.VII 1957, 3); Тішиться дитина — Забавка чудна: Надимає з мила Пухирці вона (Дніпрова Чайка, Тв., 1960, 305); Чоловік, одвернувшись од берега, став дивитися на зелений, прошитий білими смугами пухирців, пінистий слід від гвинта (Вадим Собко, Скеля.., 1961, 7); Пляшки були поприщені від шийки до дна білими пухирцями, мов насінням з дині (Петро Панч, II, 1956, 70); Найдрібніші бронхи закінчуються легеневими пухирцями, на тонких стінках яких в.. комірки (Анатомія і фізіологія людини, 8 кл., 1957, 72).

Запит "пухирці на огірках" має 25 400 сторінок в індексі [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%86%D1%96%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85)

Аналогічно до "презервативи з пухирцями"

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до цього сайту! Вітаю з якісним першим дописом!

Comment: Як на мене, то *пухирець" це щось із рідиною всередині, як-от коли натер руки. Гадаю, що у нас це слово часто вживають у обговорюваному значені, бо калькують з російської "пупьірьішки".

Answer (score 0):

Гуглоперекладач у цьому випадку цілковито має рацію:
[image: навіть гуглоперекладач знає слово пухирці]

Росіяни не заперечують: [https://translate.academic.ru/пупырышек/ru/uk/](https://translate.academic.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BA/ru/uk/)

Comment: У тексті запитання я уточнив які саме "пупьірьішки" мене цікавлять. Гадаю, що пухирці не пасують для цього значення. Із прикладів вжитку ми бачимо, що пухирці це щось наповнене плином (газом чи рідиною).

Comment: Я також змінив заголовок запитання, щоб уникнути плутанини.